# Cannot add external javascript to Facebook Pages

Tags: javascript, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-plus, facebook-social-plugins

I have an app which is embedded in a facebook page which happens to be an iframe.
There seems to be fb security concerns over usage of external javascript links. So I have replaced all my external links by either downloading them or some other tweak

For eg. js css libraries hosted at googleapis .

However I am facing a serious issue while removing the dependency of a 3rd party called 'Share This' which happens to be a plugin for share widgets of Social Websites like Fb,Twitter,Google Plus.

I have checked some other options like addthis.com but it again depends on importing external javascript which would be an issue again.

Share buttons of twitter and facebook given by them are HTML solution and would require share URL to be specified in advance but my share buttons will get the url to be shared dynamically after some process.

Is there any way which I could create Facebook , Twitter , Google Plus share buttons dynamically with custom url to share ( not the website page Url ).

Any help would be really appreciated ! :)

Cheers :)